# Python (Pandas) script reformatting csv file not working with different file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, reformatting

With some help I have created this script to change formatting in csv file. New file is reformatted as shown in the example.
Python script looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
# opening first file (base file) to be formatted
df = pd.read_csv('TTF-Offline-INFO.csv', sep=": \s+", engine='python', names=['data', 'values'])

# creating columns with headers: /path_to_file/:file.ttf 
df['dana_czcionka'] = df['data'].str.split(':').str[0]

print('\n--- df ---\n')
print(df.to_string())

with open('newTTF-Offline-INFO.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    
# grouping the values with groups named like: 
# /path_to_file/:file.ttf 
    for name, data in df.groupby('dana_czcionka'):
        print('\n---', name, '---\n')
        
        headers = (data['data'] + ":").to_list()
        print(headers)
    
        values = data['values'].to_list()
        print(values)
        values.insert(0, name)
        #writer.writerow(headers) 
        writer.writerow(values)
            
# saving new edited file as new file

print('\n--- file ---\n')
print(open('newTTF-Offline-INFO.csv').read())
```

What this script does is changing file like that:

```
/Path_to_file/BaiJamjuree-Italic.ttf:Family:              Bai Jamjuree
/Path_to_file/BaiJamjuree-Italic.ttf:Subfamily:           Italic
/Path_to_file/BaiJamjuree-Italic.ttf:Full name:           Bai Jamjuree Italic
```

to this CSV format. It rewrites the file and changes columns to rows so I can easily work with the file in excel:

```
/Path_to_file/BaiJamjuree-Italic.ttf,Bai Jamjuree,Italic,Bai Jamjuree Italic
```

It is working very well but I have second file to reformat and the second file causes an error.

```
ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 5860, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Line 5860: (and few before and after)

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/krzysztofpaszta/Library/Fonts/NotoSansBhaiksuki-Regular.ttf:Unique ID:           2.001;GOOG;NotoSansBhaiksuki-Regular
5860 - /System/Volumes/Data/Users/krzysztofpaszta/Library/Fonts/NotoSansBhaiksuki-Regular.ttf:Description:         Designed by Monotype design team.
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/krzysztofpaszta/Library/Fonts/NotoSansBhaiksuki-Regular.ttf:Designer:            Monotype Design Team
```

I have no idea where is the problem here. The line looks like every other line and new file which I want to reformat looks very similar to the first edited file which is working smoothly